# Multiboot usb stick with Mountain Lion, Windows 7, lInux, Freebsd

Tags: partition, usb, multi-boot

Looking for way how to carry always an USB stick (16GB) what allow me *live rescue boot* for different OSes. Is possible manage multiboot USB stick with 3 or 4 operating systems:

- Windows 7
- Mountain Lion
- Linux
- Freebsd

Here is probably no problem for the latter 3, but OS X need GUID(?) and therefore here are(?) probably some problems.

Some pointers would be great. Prefering creating the stick on ML/OS-X from original ISO images (Win7, Xubuntu, Freebsd 9.0) and if it is needed for something using VirtualBox.

Ps: If Win7 causes problems, can miss it - so enough to have OSX/Linux/Freebsd

Answer (score 2):

OS X has no problems with MBR partitioned disks. It only checks for MBR when you first install the OS, but after that, doesn’t. If you want to be able to reinstall using the USB install disk, you can.

Just restoring the original ISOs to different partitions on the USB disk will be fine, as long as a Mac is concerned. Other legacy computers, (usually built before 2008) may be a problem.